# Word Cannot Start the converter WPFT632

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I'm having a problem with this error say's `Word Cannot Start the converter WPFT632`  I'm using word 2016
[Sample error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUZC0.png)

```
filepath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\BIOMETRICS NA LAGING GAGAMITIN\Attendance\Payslips\Payslip.pdf"

oDoc.SaveAs(filepath, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
```

Comment: If you try saving as a user, does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bookmark on your word application to start the converter WPFT632

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same problem during execution compiled program (using Interop.Word) on the client's PC. "Run as Administrator" resolved it.